# Swagger UI Not Accessible in ASP.NET 4.5 Application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 web api application for the backend with an AngularJS 1.5.4 frontend and have added the swashbuckle package.  When I go to localhost:9000/swagger I get redirected to my login page.

I'm not too sure where my problem is coming from so I don't know what information to include.

What could potentially fix my issue of not being able to access the swagger/ui/index page?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me, I added this rule to the Web.config file.

```
<rule name="Swagger" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="swagger" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
   <action type="None" />
 </rule>
```